# LibSVM Cost Weights for Unbalanced Data Doesn't Work

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I have a data set that number of negative labeled values are 163 times of number of positive labeled values so I have a unbalanced data set. I have tried that:

```
model = svmtrain(trainLabels, trainFeatures, '-h 0 -b 1 -s 0 -c 10 -w1 163 -w-1 1');
[predicted_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testLabels, testFeatures, model, '-b 1');
```

and accuracy was nearly 99% and I searched and found that: http://agbs.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/km/bb/showthread.php?tid=376&page=1 at post #7 it says

> have you tried weighting on a smaller scale (ie: <1)

and I changed it to:

```
model = svmtrain(trainLabels, trainFeatures, '-h 0 -b 1 -s 0 -c 10 -w1 0.5 -w-1 0.003');
[predicted_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testLabels, testFeatures, model, '-b 1');
```

I have still high accuracy every time because of unbalanced data. Any ideas?

**PS:** I am trying to implement the first challenge of KDD Cup 2008 - Breast Cancer. **I want to rank the candidates by decreasing order.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to the reason, that your negative and positive examples are poorly seperable. 
I would prepare different datasets by downsampling the majority class and using all the the minority class examples, then learn svm on all of the datasets. Use voting then. This worked for me